# Moving FParsec code to an F# module does not work

Tags: module, f#, fparsec

I'm a newbie in F# and in FParsec and have problems with moving my FParsec code into an F# module using VS 2022 Community Edition, DotNet 6.0.

My use case is this: My console app solution currently consists of a single `Program.fs` that I can build and run without any problems. Now, I want to move some parts of my code to an F# module so I can reuse it. That causes weird type errors I cannot resolve.

This is a working example to reproduce my problem. Consider a console app solution consisting of a single simple `Program.fs` file containing

```
open FParsec

let p = pstring "foo"
let result = run p "foo"

printfn "%O" result
```

I can build and run the code without any problems.

Now, if I create a module `MyModule.fs` like this:

```
module MyModule
open FParsec
let p = pstring "foo"
```

and open it in `Program.fs` like this:

```
open FParsec
open MyModule
let result = run p "foo"
printfn "%O" result
```

I get the following two build errors:

```
In MyModule.fs, line 3: Error   FS0030  Value restriction. The value 'p' has been inferred to have generic type val p: Parser<string,'_a>    
Either make the arguments to 'p' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation. 

In Program.fs, line 3: Error    FS0001  Type mismatch. Expecting a 'Parser<'a,unit>' but given a 'Parser<string,obj>'    
The type 'unit' does not match the type 'obj'
```

Why do I get these two errors although the code split with the module seems to be semantically identical to the previous code without the module and how can I resolve these errors?

Comment: The problem is the value restriction (you can search here for it). In the first scenario the value restriction gets disambiguated by the `run` function, that's why it works with that setting.

Comment: So is it a 'feature, not a bug' that the F# compiler cannot disambiguate across modules?

Comment: Module compilation is independent of its use, so type information on the uses outside the module are not taking into account to compile the module.

Comment: Is then there some way to separate the parser grammar of my language into a module without having to run the parser inside the module? I would like to run the parser in the main Program.fs but define it in the module.   Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you can specify the full type, add an explicit argument, all alternative solutions to the value restriction problem will apply here.

Comment: See https://web.archive.org/web/20180209105359/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @Gus in the comments, the problem is that parsers have a second type parameter for user data, that was disambiguated by the call to `run` in the original code but not in the modularized code.

You can fix this by specifying the full type for the parser:

```ml
let p: Parser<string, unit> = pstring "foo"
```

Then, when you combine several parsers, you'll only need to specify this once and it will disambiguate for all parsers that use it or that it uses. It's typically done on the final parser.

```ml
let p1 = pstring "foo"

let p2 = pstring "bar"

let p: Parser<string, unit> = p1 <|> p2
```

Comment: Thx, it solved my problem. I could not figure out by myself the right syntax for explicitly typing the p variable, since the F# compiler error says "Parser<string,'_a>" and not "Parser<string,unit>", a thing misleading a newbie like me :-).